# Python Check weight plik.txt

Tags: python

I need function to check in `name.txt` variable if variable will changed print 1 and again if variable 2 times change again print 1. Its possible to do in python?

http://pastebin.com/Qa0ed3nM

```
fr = open("plik.txt",'r')
first_length = len(str(fr.read()))
while True:
    text = str(fr.read())
    if(len(text)!=first_length):
        fr.close()
        fw = open("plik.txt","w")
        fw.write(text)
        fw.close()
        print("done")
        break;
```

Comment: Also, indentation is important in python syntax. I tried to fix your indentation mut may have gotten it wrong.

Comment: I need all time check text in file   i check 1 time 2 time and 3 debug error

Comment: I'm going to create script   check information in file  plik.txt  when in plik.txt write 1 i changed it to 2 cmd print 'done'  again change print'done'